# Let $U$ be an open subset of a smooth manifold $M$. Is $T_{p}U \subseteq T_{p}M$?

Tags: real-analysis, differential-geometry, differential-topology

My question is as stated in the title. It seems like a very trivial matter, but I want to know if it is customary to officially treat  $T_{p}U$ as a subset of $T_{p}M$. It seems like this is true, for if $f:M \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ is smooth, then $f$ is also a smooth function on $U \subseteq M$ so that for $v \in  T_{p}U$, $v(f)$ is well-defined. This would allow us to say $T_{p}U \subseteq T_{p}M$.

On the other hand, if we are being more precise, $f$ is NOT a smooth function defined on $M$, but its restriction $f|_{U}$ is. Therefore, if we are being strict about this, we can't make the above argument.

I know that $T_{p}U$ and $T_{p}M$ are isomorphic, and the two sets are often "identified" through that relation, but I am wondering if I can officially treat one as a subset of the other.

Thanks!

Comment: The answer depends on precisely what you mean by *officially*. If you mean, Is there a *canonical* isomorphism $T_p U \stackrel{\cong}{\to} T_p M$, then the answer is yes.

Comment: Indeed, if $\iota : U \hookrightarrow M$ is the inclusion map, then the isomorphism is simply $T_p \iota : T_p U \to T_p M$. Then, the compatibility you describe is just that for $v \in T_p U$, $$(T_p \iota v)(f) = v(\iota^* f) = v(f\vert_U) .$$

Comment: I am trying to prove that if $df_{p}:T_{p}M\rightarrow T_{f(p)}U$ is surjective, and $U \subseteq N$ is open, then $df_{p}:T_{p}M \rightarrow T_{f(p)}N$ is surjective. 

Let $v'' \in T_{f(p)}N$. Since $di_{f(p)}: T_{f(p)}U \rightarrow T_{f(p)}N$ is surjective, then there exists $v' \in T_{f(p)}U$ such that $di_{f(p)}(v')=v''$. Since $df_{p}:T_{p}M\rightarrow T_{f(p)}U$ is surjective, there is a $v \in T_{p}M$ such that $df_{p}(v)=v'$.

But, is it the case that $df_{p}(v)=v''$? Let $g \in C^{\infty}(M)$.

Comment: Then,

$$v''(g)=di_{f(p)}(v')(g)=v'(g \circ i)=df_{p}(v)(g \circ i).$$

Now, the proof is complete if we can say $v''(g)=df_{p}(v)(g)$, but right now we have $v''(g)=df_{p}(v)(g \circ i).$ However, $g \circ i$ is simply $g$ restricted to $U$, so this seems like only a notational issue. Nevertheless, $v''$ is defined on $T_{f(p)}N$ and $df_{p}(v)$ is defined on $T_{f(p)}U$, which are different spaces. If $T_{f(p)}U \subseteq T_{f(p)}N$, or $C^{\infty}(M) \subseteq C^{\infty}(U)$, the problem is solved.

Comment: Look Prop.3.9 in Lee's Smooth Manifolds. It is proved quite detailed there.

Answer (score 2):

Strictly speaking, the sets $T_pU$ and $T_pM$ are disjoint. However, as Travis Wilse pointed out in his comments, there is a *natural isomorphism* $T_p\iota : T_pU \to T_pM$.

Thus, for all practical purposes it will do no harm to write $T_pU = T_pM$ simply because we have a canonical identification of these objects. In that sense we can also write $TU = TM  \mid_U \subset TM$ for the tangent bundles.

In the literature you will find many examples of such an abuse of notation. Don't worry, it is not dangerous.